# HickariCP постоянно предупреждает о проблеме соединения с БД

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, spring-boot

Нужна помощь в конфигурации HickariCP на Spring-boot 2.1. Постоянно появляются сообщения

> HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7db2a70b (No operations allowed after connection closed.). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

В pom исключил tomcat-jdbc

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Конфигурация HickariCP в yml

```
hikari:
  idle-timeout: 600000
  max-lifetime: 1800000
  connection-timeout: 30000
  minimum-idle: 5
  maximum-pool-size: 20
```

mysql-connector-java - 8.0.13, вдруг это важно.

Comment: `Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.` - попробуйте задать `max-lifetime` меньше значение

Comment: Пробовал и 800000, и 1000000, и 1400000, если указать еще меньше, то устанавливается дефолтное значение - 1800000

Answer (score 0):

В mysql wait_timeout и interactive_timeout были указаны 10 и 50 секунд соответственно, изменил на дефолтное значение на 28800 и ошибка исчезла